# Filter/Sort IntelliSense suggestions in Visual Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets

Recently I started to use Visual Code which seems to be a very nice editor, but one thing which bothers me is order in which IntelliSense JavaScript snippets suggestions appear (when I type "for" I would expect first suggestions to be defined JavaScript snippets, but instead I got lots of objects and interfaces which make me iterate through list). I would appreciate if somebody could give me a hint how can organize IntelliSense suggestions for JavaScript/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option allowing you to change order of suggested snippets `settings.json`:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"
```